# CppDB compilation errors

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I followed the following steps in order to build CppDB:

```
svn co http://cppcms.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cppcms/cppdb/trunk cppdb-trunk
cd cppdb-trunk
cmake ~/Desktop/cppdb-trunk
make
make install
```

Afterwards, I'm trying to compile and run the file *example1.cpp* from the examples directory.

When I run `gcc example1.cpp` I get the following errors:

> /tmp/ccGWenrv.o: In function `main':
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to`std::allocator::allocator()'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to`cppdb::session::session(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to`std::allocator::~allocator()'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `cppdb::session::operator<<(char const*)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to`cppdb::statement::operator<<(void (*)(cppdb::statement&))'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `cppdb::statement::~statement()'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to`cppdb::session::operator<<(char const*)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `cppdb::statement::operator<<(void (*)(cppdb::statement&))'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to`cppdb::statement::~statement()'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `cppdb::statement::statement()'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to`cppdb::session::operator<<(char const*)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `cppdb::statement::operator<<(tm const&)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to`cppdb::statement::operator<<(char const*)'
>   example1.cpp:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `cppdb::statement::operator=(cppdb::statement const&)'

etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to compile `c++` files using `g++`. `gcc` assumes `C` language. `g++ example1.cpp` what does it shows?

Answer (score 2):

Try `g++ example1.cpp -lcppdb`.  You need to link against the C++ run-time library (using `g++` instead of `gcc` takes care of that) and against CppDB itself (the `-lcppdb` part).  If GCC cannot find the `-lcppdb` library, you'll have to provide the path using `-L`, and you may have to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at run time as well.

Comment: Thank you, it compiled using the -lcppdb flag.